# car battery to charge deep-cycle (service) battery circuit

Tags: batteries, relay, battery-charging, ampere-hour

I need to connect my car battery ([TUDOR TB500](https://azerbaijan.desertcart.com/products/66000870-tudor-tb-500-exide-technica-50-ah-12-v-car-battery-dimensions-207-x-175-x-190-right-terminal)) to a deep-cycle battery that I will use for little services ([LIFEPO4 12.8V 42Ah](https://creabest.it/products/lifepo4-batteria-al-litio-12-8v-42ah-per-camper-campeggio-barche)). I will put a voltage sensitive relay (that cut in at 13.3V and cut out at 12.8V, 140A) in between to isolate them. My question is: if my car battery is a 50Ah with a peak of 450A, the relay has a 140A limit and the recommended charging current for the deep-cycle one is 8-20A, do I risk to "kill" the relay or the deep-cycle battery? Cause my understanding is that for some seconds they will receive 450A. In case, how do I limit this current to avoid >20A without losing tension?

I googled and looked here but couldn't find a proper answer to this

Comment: Why not get a split-charge relay specifically designed for this purpose. Check out places that do caravans and those that do electric winches.

Comment: +1 to Mike for a new term to me "split-charge relay"   but requires alternator tap before diodes.  VSR is similar to split charge as it connects immediately after starter releases.  https://www.12voltplanet.co.uk/split-charging.html  None of these solutions are optimal, but some are cheaper, longer life than others.  The optimal is to switch exactly when voltages are matched so that Δ I = Δ V / ESRs  is < contact rating

Comment: @SolarMike I was googling your great term (as Tony highlighted) and ended up in the same guide he pointed to (https://www.12voltplanet.co.uk/split-charging.html) but it doesn't look like they worry about the peak amperage at start. It also has a video (https://youtu.be/a9p7IYfmkJk) in which he utilizes a 140A VSR just like I do. I was wondering if this prevent the peak to be transmitted to the auxiliary battery or not and if this is not a problem for the VSR itself

Comment: Not sure what you all googled, but here is a link: https://www.wiredcampers.co.uk/collections/12v-split-charge-relay-kits

Comment: Mike's VSR label says 13.3 ON , 12.8V OFF looks about right but still has massive surge on a drained aux battery but calls it a VS SCR !  (voltage sensitive split-charge relay 150A)

Answer (score 0):

I started to think how a smart relay would operate and stopped and realized it was just a current limited VSR.

So my casual advice is to use an inrush current limiter or  heater and 6V light bulb across it as an indicator to limit the contactor current yet still be able to slow charge it or fast charge with a bypass relay on the series R after Δ V < x

There is no doubt that inrush arcs will age the relay contacts as well as open circuit on high inductive loads.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvHLBq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The diodes used inside alternators would be ideal to use as a diode OR battery isolator switch. But then the voltage sensing of the 3 phase bridge in the alternator would have to be modified to account for the voltage drop which diminishes as current drops, so not that significant of a Δ V ...

Leading me to think out loud that the diode battery isolator is best compromise using alternator diodes + heatsink.

[image]

12voltplanet.co.uk/split-charging.html

Comment: This is great answer, thank you! While I kept thinking about this I thought about the rest of electrical equipment in the car, which is connected to the starter battery as well. If they all receive a spike current of 450A at engine start, you should see the lights increasing their power, when actually you see them become dimmer. So I guess the starter is probably able to "drain" that high current from the circuit leaving the rest of components with less, am I misunderstanding something?